# using forEach with SignalR return value (List<string>) in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

Hi i invoke a method with using SignalR and i want to use return value as foreach loop in javascript for create a table

**Hub :**

```
 public void OrderAllSales()
        {
           List<string> tableValue = new List<string>();
             /*
                Do something and fill tableValue with 
                <tr>
                <td>....</td>
                <td>....</td> 
                </tr> 
                block for every item
              */ 
              Clients.All.SendListOfAll(tableValue);
        }
```

**Cshtml**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr style="margin-left: 10px">
        <td>Price (₺)</td>
        <td>BTC (฿)</td>
        <td>Total (₺)</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="HistoryGrid">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var bitcoinHub = $.connection.bitcoinHub;

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $("#allSales").click(function () {
                    bitcoinHub.server.orderAllSales();
                });

                bitcoinHub.client.sendListOfAll(function (x) {
                    x.forEach(Create);
                });
            });

        function Create(item) {
            $("#HistoryGrid").prepend(item);
        }
     });
    </script>
```

i can invoke server method but i couldn't use this return value for create a table

Comment: Do you receive anything in `x`? What seems to be the issue.

Comment: yes  'Clients.All.SendListOfAll(tableValue);' this is return to x and i want to use this x for reach this returned List

Comment: I get that but right now you are not returning anything but a null value--this is null: `List<string> tableValue;`

Comment: No it's full look this is the full method --- 
 http://codepad.org/fWxihf91

Comment: Your code looks fine. But you still have not answered my question: Are you sure you are receiving anything in `x`? Do this and see: `bitcoinHub.client.sendListOfAll(function (x) { alert(x); });`

Comment: i didn't see anything when code run with alert(x) - method invoke is succeed. Alert block didn't show

Comment: Well then there is your issue. You need to figure out why you are not getting anything in `x`. My assumption was true.

Comment: i am new at mvc,js and signalR so i mostly can't understand where is issue :D so how can i solve this i think the code is true in server method. And it has to be send it to client as "x" for me but i don't know why this is happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure out it.

**Wrong Code :**

```
bitcoinHub.client.sendListOfAll(function (x) {
                    x.forEach(Create);
                });
```

**Right Code :**

```
 bitcoinHub.client.sendListOfAll = function (x) {
                        x.forEach(Create);
                    };
```

The error is using () instead of = while trying catch returning method at client side.